# Issue in older android versions with branch.io in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to use [Branch](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Cordova-Ionic-PhoneGap-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK) in my Cordova Android app. Everything works fine in android versions above 4.4.2
But, in all versions below android 4.4.4 , Branch does not work.

I have done

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(Branch);
    Branch.initSession().then(function (res) {
       alert('something);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        alert('errref:'+err)
    });

    alert('outer alert');

}
```

It prints an object on console, as expected. and nothing else happen on versions below 4.4.4 
While on 4.4.4+ , it gives an alert "something" and "outer alert"

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 4.4.4 (KitKat) permission model changed dramatically.
Try adding permissions manually:

```
Add the following entry to your application's config.xml:

<branch-config>
    <android-prefix value="READ_FROM_DASHBOARD" />
    <host name="bnc.lt" scheme="https" />
</branch-config>
```

There are a lot of good docs here - https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Cordova-Ionic-PhoneGap-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK

Comment: Already added this :( Now I installed older Branch 1.8.0 and its working